# Ckeditor 4 justify with font and color not working together

Tags: ckeditor4.x

I have installed all 3 plugins and they work only if the others are not configured.
This is the config I have:

```js
        config.extraPlugins = 'justify';
        config.extraPlugins = 'colordialog';
        config.extraPlugins = 'colorbutton';
        config.extraPlugins = 'font';
};
```

Once I keep only one active, it works.

I need all of them to work together.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind.
I've downloaded the full build and it works there just fine.